# How to deploy MVC4 application to Windows Server 2008 from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008-r2

Well this is probably supposed to be obvious, but I can't figure out how to deploy to Server 2008 instead of the Windows Azure Cloud. Help?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is a "Publish" option in Solution Explorer. Right click on the project name and click Publish. The server also required the installation of Web Deploy and a few other things before I could deploy to it.